# Ruby: Adding items to store hash and shopping cart array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am just learning Ruby.  Trying to add items to products hash in a Store object and then add some of those items to a cart array.  I can get the store object to be created with store = Store.new that has the products hash and cart array.  But don't know how to add products to the hash and then to the array.  I am probably not even close, but here is what I have so far:

```
class Store
 def initialize
   @products = {"item1" => 2.5, "item2" => 3.89, "item3" => 4.65, "item4" => 3.0, "item5" => 6.5}
   @cart = []

 end

 def add_to_cart( item, price )
   @cart << 
 end

 def add_product( item, price )
   @products <<
 end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: do you want to be able to set the price when adding to cart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def add_to_cart( item )
    @cart << item
end

def add_product( item, price )
    @products[item] = price
end

def total
    @cart.inject(0){|sum, item| sum + @products[item]}
end
```

Comment: Wow!  That did it! I kinda was on that track, but didn't realize I needed another method.  Thanks for the quick response!